# Is possible to have a "pointer" to a tree node in a functional language?

Tags: terminology, trees, functional-programming, tree-traversal

Suppose I have the following structure definition in C:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *parent, *left, *right;
}
```

If I want to represent a specific node inside a tree, all I need is a pointer to such node, which allows me to traverse the tree using the parent and children's link.

Instead, if I have a simple tree structure in a functional programming language, for example in Haskell

```
Data TreeNode a = Nil | Node a (TreeNode a) (TreeNode a)
```

is there a way to represent the concept of a node, which allows to explore the tree "locally"?

The question arises from approaching the [lowest common ancestor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor), since I don't know even how to define the problem in a functional setting: what does it mean "taking in input two nodes"? Should one use a different tree representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) data structure.